# Does faculty hiring process vary from institution to institutions?

Tags: faculty-application, academic-life

I interviewed for a faculty position back in September 7 and 8. All interview for this position was done the next week. On October 3 I followed up with the search committee chair and they replied they sent the recommendation to the dean. I haven’t heard anything so far, although my interview went pretty well. I sent another follow up email to the Dept. Chair regarding the Status yesterday and they replied they are internally processing it with the HR and hope to get back me soon. Does this indicating that they already offered the position someone verbally and now processing with HR? I hope some of you who are experienced with the systems can explain it. TIA.

Comment: It's that time of year again....so many questions about "does this cryptic statement mean I got the job?" The only answer we can give is the one below -- we do not know, and every university's process is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Does this indicating that they already offered the position someone verbally and now processing with HR?" Nobody can know other than the people involved. It may be that they want to make *you* the offer and it is going through HR right now. Or perhaps you are right. There is nothing you can do other than wait.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. Looks like it’s a real black box. Usually the HR Starts processing after offering verbally, that’s why I was confused.

Answer (score 7):

*Does faculty hiring process vary from institution to institutions?* **Yes**

Comment: I was wondering what does this internal processing with HR meaning? do they verbally offer first then process with HR? Or do they process with HR and then offer verbally following formal offer letter?

Answer (score 2):

If they didn't want to divulge whether you or someone else has been selected, but you could find out by asking here, then they would say less, otherwise they are telling you too much.

If they wanted you to know more, such as to understand if you are the top candidate or whether you are no longer in consideration, they would say that explicitly.

Take their statement at face value: the process is ongoing, third parties are involved as they always are, they hope to get back to you soon with more information once they have it.